# Cannot Edit XSL attribute value using Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I have an **XSL** file where I want to update my attribute tag value using **java** code. 
This is my **XSL** file :-

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:attribute-set name="__frontmatter">
        <xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to read parent tag `"__frontmatter"` , then under this child node tag `"text-align"` and update the value  `center`.

I know to read Node name from **XML** file , but this is something confusing me, how will I read `xsl:attribute-set` and  `name="xyz"` from java code?

**EDIT:-** Adding method.

```
private static void updateElementValue(Document doc) {
        String a="right";
        NodeList frontmatterr = doc.getElementsByTagName("text-align");
        Element e = null;
        for(int i=0; i<frontmatterr.getLength();i++){
            e = (Element) frontmatterr.item(i);
            Node name = emp.getElementsByTagName("text-align").item(0).getFirstChild();
            name.setNodeValue(name.getNodeValue().valueOf(a));
        }
    }
```

My java code where I am trying to read xsl node.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you trying to modify the XSL (as an XML document) from within a Java program? Or, are you trying to use the XSL from within a Java program and intercept its processing at runtime to change its behavior?  The first is easy to do, just treat the XSL as an XML document. The second is a bit harder.  You'd have to load the XSL as an XML document, modify its DOM, and then use it to instantiate a `Transformer`.

Comment: @JimGarrison I am trying to do the first one , modify XSL from java program. I have shown my XSL file ,`<xsl:attribute name="text-align">center</xsl:attribute>` . I am facing problem in reading the node `<xsl:attribute>` because of  `:`. Unlike XML it the node name is not simple.

Comment: The easiest approach to transform XSLT with a Java program is to use Java to run a second XSLT that performs the transformation. If you don't want to use XSLT then you need to explain which Java API (DOM, JDOM, XOM, SAX) you try to use and show us that code.

Comment: @MartinHonnen I cannot use another XSLT file as it will be always hard coded. the scenario is same either I change in this file or that file. I am not getting how will I read attribute `name="text-align"` and change it to some other value from input fields.

Comment: Do you know XPath at least and have considered selecting e.g. `xsl:stylesheet/xsl:attribute-set[@name = '__frontmatter']/xsl:attribute[@name = 'text-align']` with XPath and then setting `setTextContent("right")`?

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/xslt/xpath.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Comment: @MartinHonnen No, I don't have idea of Xpath. Let me try.

Answer (score 1):

Although you say in your comment that you "cannot use another XSLT file" I think XSLT is the right tool to manipulate XSLT so I post a suggestion here, with the XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:param name="new-text-align">right</xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xsl:attribute-set[@name = '__frontmatter']/xsl:attribute[@name = 'text-align']">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="$new-text-align"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqo/1, you can transform the original XSLT you have to

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

    <xsl:attribute-set name="__frontmatter">
        <xsl:attribute name="text-align">right</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

within the Java JAXP API you would simply set up a `Transformer` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html with above XSLT as the source (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newTransformer-javax.xml.transform.Source-) and use the original XSLT as the input `Source` and would get the new XSLT as the `Result` of the `transform` method.

Comment: This is helpful , thank you for the detailed answer. but I need to achieve this from java code. I have plenty of fields like this.

Comment: Like you have mentioned in the above link `<xsl:param name="new-text-align">center</xsl:param>`. How will I achieve this from java code. Like from dropbox select option `right` and it should get `<xsl:param name="new-text-align">right</xsl:param>`.